# Words to Differentiate Ordinary and Lower-Dimensional Measures

Tags: measure-theory

Are there words or phrases that contrast 'ordinary measure', i.e. the $n$-dimensional measure of a subset of an $n$-dimensional space, with 'lower-dimensional' measures, i.e. the $m$-dimensional measure of a subset of an $n$-dimensional space, where $m<n$? For example, the area of a line segment in the plane is $0$ and its length is a positive number.

Comment: Can you be more precise? Are you talking about a specific measure (usually called Lesbesgue measure)? Are you talking about a class of measures (possibly those that are absolutely continuous to Lesbesgue measure - a.k.a. the space $L^1(\mathbb R^n)$)? On $\mathbb R$, how would the usual measure supported on the Cantor set play into what you want? I don't think this question is possible to answer without clarifications.

Comment: It's not clear in what context you would have two notions of "measure of a set".  The "usual" measure in $n$-dimensional space is Lebesgue measure there, but not every subset of $\mathbb R^n$ is assigned a "measure" in this sense.  What you have in mind with respect to "lower-dimensional measures" would bear clarification, perhaps by giving Readers an example.

Comment: I think that if an author wants to assign a non-trivial measure to lower dimensional varieties of $\mathbb R^n$, then much more exposition is needed to define how this is being done than merely using "words or phrases" that connote the "ordinary measure" on $\mathbb R^n$.  The example of a line segment suggests that you have in mind a finite (positive) measure *singular* with respect to Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^n$, but it's hard to make recommendations with regard to terminology without knowing more about your intended application.

Comment: I often see people use the word *volume* to refer to a particular "natural" measure on a space.  If you talk about the "measure" of a set in $\mathbb{R}^n$, say, it could be ambiguous, but if you talk about its volume, it's understood that you mean its $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure.

Answer (score 0):

There are several notions of "lower dimensional measures". Probably the best start is to look up the definition of "Hausdorff measure" (but beware that you need some solid background in measure theory).